# Reading group of bytes in an external file using Qt and C++

Tags: c++, qt

A question yet unresolved.
I'm working with `QFile` and `QDataStream` to write and read data into a file. My aim is to write, read and manage 32 groups of 5 bytes at the time.
I began to divide my reading loop as follows:

```
QFile myfile("myfile.dat");
myfile.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
QDataStream in(&myfile);
QDataStream out(&myfile);
for(quint8 index = 0; index < 32; index++)  // 32 groups
{
    for(idx_item=0; idx_item<5; idx_item++) // reading of 5 bytes 
    {
        in >> DateErrArray[idx_item];
        ... divide the 5 bytes and put where they're needed...
    }
    ... do other operations before the end of file
}
```

My question are:

1. Does is it a good way to use a dual "for" loop to read groups of bytes or there's something better and simple?
2. Once I read my file, I have to write a further 5 bytes group, supposing in a known position (example: after 20 bytes, corresponding to after the 4th 5 bytes group): how can I "point to" the position I want?

Comment: Typically with i/o operations, it's more efficient to read in larger chunks at a time and then parsing out the data. But it depends on the use-case I suppose.

Comment: Ad 1. It depends on requirements. From code readability point of view it is Ok. If you take into consideration performance - who cares if data are small, and this is bad if data are big. Ad 2. How large data do you operate? If small (looks like it)  then just read a whole thing do not make things over complicated.